# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Bluetooth dongle not working

Tags: bluetooth, dongle

I have seen some issues with the Bluetooth dongle but mostly because of the lack of firmware... none of them solved my issue, the gnome-control-center still doesn't recognize it.
Some information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.17.0-1006-oem
```

Running lsusb i can find the dongle:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:a725 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

When i run `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`
i get

```
[    1.963547] usb 1-8: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    3.499204] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.499411] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.499413] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.499416] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.499417] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.499420] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.564632] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.564637] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.564640] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 3207.065478] usb 1-8: Product: Bluetooth Radio
```

It seems like everything is ok and it should work... but it simply don't.

Comment: What does `rfkill list` show?

Comment: works for me with the exception, that my headsets won't auto connect (manual works fine). linux neon